# How do I put to span next to each other on twitter bootstrap mobile view

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

Hey im trying to achieve this look:[image]

Problem is I can never put 2 spans next to each other they always stack up and im trying to not have that happen as you can see in the picture. Any Twitter Bootstrap CSS genius have an idea?

And just to be a bit more specific this is only for mobile view meaning that I am using the bootstrap class "visible-phone" on my container class.

Comment: did you try .row-fluid > .span6 ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean but regardless what span I put (1 2 3 4 5 6) it  will always take up 100% width on mobile for bootstrap.

Comment: are you using .row or .row-fluid to wrap those spans

Answer (score 0):

### From Bootstrap 3 Documentation

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Don't want your columns to simply stack in smaller devices? Use the extra small and medium device grid classes by adding .col-xs-* .col-md-* to your columns. See the example below for a better idea of how it all works.

Comment: I see bootstrap updated their website and stuff does the col-xs still apply to the last version (meaning when there website wasn't that purple color)

Comment: Yep! that's bootstrap 3.0 I guess you are using 2.3

Comment: it didn't seem to work I copied their example and gave it a background color just to see how it looks and its still taking 100% of the mobile screen. this is what I did <div class="container visible-phone">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6" style="background:#F00;">.col-xs-6</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6" style="background:#03F;">.col-xs-6</div>
</div>
<hr />
</div><!---container END---->